# Getting data from 50 service bus queue for a real time dashboard in a azure web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, azure, azureservicebus

Using the code as shown [here](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-Server-Side-Timers-and-SignalR-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx).. I was able to create a web app that every 30 seconds sent data to client using System.Threading.Timer.

I was able to add some code which received data from a service bus queue using Messaging factory and Messaging receiver and based on that sent data to signalR client instead of hard-coding as in the mentioned example.

Now my real application gets data from 50 such queue..

Theoretically, I could create 50 timer objects which would call 50 different methods which in turn would call service bus queue.

I would sincerely appreciate if someone could suggest the right way to achieve my goal..

Thanks

Comment: @Mr.B I have worked with async await.. But how would I create 50 timer objects using async?? Or do I create standard timer objects and just call the queue using async methods?? Tx..

Answer (score 1):

The [message pump pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.onmessage.aspx) seems like it would be a good fit for this application. You create a separate client for each queue and configure each one to automatically listen for messages in its queue and process them as they come in.

```
foreach (var queueName in queueNames){
  var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
  queueClient.OnMessage(message =>
  {
    // Do work here
    Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Recieved message {0} on queue {1}", message.MessageId, queueName));
  });
}
```